# Large time required while replacing the text

Tags: livecode

Large amount of time required while replacing the words from the array. The array consist of (`y[1]` and `y[2]`) more than 25000 words. Is it possible to reduce the time?. Iam using below code for replacing.

```
on mouseUp
    put the field SRText into myArrayToBe
    split myArrayToBe by CR
    put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
    repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
    put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
    split y by colon
    put y[1] into searchStr
    put y[2] into replaceStr
    if searchStr is empty then
         put the  0 into m
      else
  put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml
  set the caseSensitive to true
  replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml
  set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
  end if
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Is there any error in this looping?

Comment: I provided an answer using an array, but I think I can do it much faster without using an array.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider moving the putting and setting of the htmltext outside of the repeat loop.

```
on mouseUp
 put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml
 set the caseSensitive to true
 put field "SRText" into myArrayToBe
 split myArrayToBe by CR
 repeat for each key myKey in myArrayToBe 
      put  myArrayToBe[myKey] into y
      split y by colon
      put y[1] into searchStr
      put y[2] into replaceStr
      if searchStr is empty then
           put 0 into m
      else   
           replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & \
                 "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & \
                 "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote \
                 & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml               
      end if
 end repeat
 set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
```

end mouseUp

Answer (score 0):

Try `repeat for each` instead of `repeat with`. Usually, `repeat for each` is much quicker. It looks like arrays tend to slow down repeat for each a little. A simple list will probably be quicker.

```
on mouseUp
     put field SRText into myArrayToBe
     put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml
     set the caseSensitive to true
     repeat for each line myLine in myArrayToBe 
          set the itemDel to colon
          if item 1 of myLine is empty then
               put 0 into m
          else
               replace item 1 of myLine with "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & \
                     "yellow" & quote & ">" & item 1 of myLine & \
                     "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & \
                     quote & ">" & item 2 of myLine & "</font>" in myHtml
          end if
     end repeat
     set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
end mouseUp
```

If the biggest problem is the blocking of the GUI, while you could accept an additional slowdown, you could also add a line `wait for 0 millisecs with messages` and some code to update a progress bar at the end of the repeat loop.

Comment: I provided an answer using an array, but I think I can do it much faster without using an array.